# Page not found while trying access controller with parameter in url

Tags: magento2, controllers, routing, parameter, request

i created a simple controller like this:

```
namespace Namespace\Module\Controller\Confirm;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{

    protected $resultPageFactory;


    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
        print_r($params);
        exit; 
    }
}
```

when i access my module controller with parameter like this, i'll get **Page not found**:

> http://baseurl.com/mymodule/confirm/token/1231dasda

when i access my module contoller without parameter in url like this, it will run the controller function:

> http://baseurl.com/mymodule/confirm

Comment: Check this URL : http://baseurl.com/mymodule/confirm/index/token/1231dasda

Comment: @SureshChikani yeah that's working,so how to make it work if i remove the index from url/?

Comment: You can do it by URL rewrite.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, I think You should run

**sudo php bin/magento setup:di:compile** after adding new controller

```
    <?php 


    namespace Namespace\Module\Controller\Confirm;

    class Index
 extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
    {

        protected $resultPageFactory;


        public function __construct(
            \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
            \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
        ) {
            $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
            parent::__construct($context);
        }

        public function execute()
        {
            $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
            print_r($params);
            exit; 
        }
    }

    ?>
```

to access frontend

> http://baseurl.com/module/confirm/index/